# Index function in a simple nested for loop not

Tags: python, python-3.x

So here is the pretty basic code i am working with, it is a function that takes a grid in the form of a tuple of tuples. In the loop I have tried to make i the rows and q the columns for the grid.

```
def myfunc(grid):  
    for i in (grid): 
        for q in i: 
            print("i.index(q): ", i.index(q), " grid.index(i)", grid.index(i))

    return True

myfunc(((1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
        (0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
        (0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
        (1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
        (0, 0, 1, 0, 0)))
```

Here is what I get:

```
i.index(q):  0  grid.index(i) 0
i.index(q):  1  grid.index(i) 0
i.index(q):  1  grid.index(i) 0
i.index(q):  0  grid.index(i) 0
i.index(q):  1  grid.index(i) 0
i.index(q):  0  grid.index(i) 1
i.index(q):  1  grid.index(i) 1
i.index(q):  0  grid.index(i) 1
i.index(q):  0  grid.index(i) 1
i.index(q):  0  grid.index(i) 1
i.index(q):  0  grid.index(i) 2
i.index(q):  0  grid.index(i) 2
```

and so on.

I expecting and want to get 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, ... for `i.index(q)`, am I not using this function correctly? This seems odd as `grid.index(i)` is working fine and when I printed q in the `for q in i:` loop I got the right values.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tuple.index` returns index of **first occurrence** of the given element:

```
In [1]: tuple.index?
Docstring:
T.index(value, [start, [stop]]) -> integer -- return first index of value.
Raises ValueError if the value is not present.
Type:      method_descriptor
```

In order to iterate over elements along with their indices, you should use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function:

```
In [2]: def myfunc(grid):
   ...:     for i, row in enumerate(grid):
   ...:         for j, elem in enumerate(row):
   ...:             print('Row #{}, elem #{}, value: {}'.format(i, j, elem))

In [3]: myfunc(((1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
   ...:         (0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
   ...:         (0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
   ...:         (1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
   ...:         (0, 0, 1, 0, 0)))
Row #0, elem #0, value: 1
Row #0, elem #1, value: 0
Row #0, elem #2, value: 0
Row #0, elem #3, value: 1
Row #0, elem #4, value: 0
Row #1, elem #0, value: 0
Row #1, elem #1, value: 1
Row #1, elem #2, value: 0
Row #1, elem #3, value: 0
Row #1, elem #4, value: 0
Row #2, elem #0, value: 0
Row #2, elem #1, value: 0
Row #2, elem #2, value: 1
Row #2, elem #3, value: 0
Row #2, elem #4, value: 1
Row #3, elem #0, value: 1
Row #3, elem #1, value: 0
Row #3, elem #2, value: 0
Row #3, elem #3, value: 0
Row #3, elem #4, value: 0
Row #4, elem #0, value: 0
Row #4, elem #1, value: 0
Row #4, elem #2, value: 1
Row #4, elem #3, value: 0
Row #4, elem #4, value: 0
```

Comment: @C.Dow, do not forget to accept answer using the tick under the post's score buttons, this will help users with same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're using them perfectly. But they're not what you want to use.

```
def myfunc(grid):  
    for (i, row) in enumerate(grid): 
        for (j, el) in enumerate(row): 
            print('{},{}'.format(i, j))
```